Why does Lyra take Brande and Talbot's ideas seriously?
In The Secret Commonwealth, the second volume of The Book of Dust, there are two philosophers, Brande and Talbot, whose books are tremendously popular, and who both seem to found their philosophy on the premise of the non-existence of daemons. This already seems strange enough given the context of the setting: since nearly everyone lives their whole life with a daemon, interacts with other people's daemons regularly, and, as we see in the book, by and large shuns people who for whatever reason do not have one, it would seem rather like denying the existence of one's right hand (unlike in our world, where not believing in the existence of a soul is rendered a rather popular position by virtue of it not being a physically visible thing that accompanies us every day of our lives).
However, even more curious, Lyra appears to take these philosophers' ideas at least half-seriously near the beginning of the book, even having an argument with Pantalaimon (a daemon!) about the matter. Now, bearing in mind all the things she has seen and knows about the nature of daemons as of the end of The Amber Spyglass—people spiritually mutilated by the permanent separation from their daemons, the ability of people like her and the witches to send their daemons away to gather information, the way daemons from people from another world can come in existence, and much more—her finding these arguments plausible seems something like Buzz Aldrin suddenly declaring the Earth to be flat.
Pantalaimon initially seems to see the ideas of Brande and Talbot as "hypnotic" and even a "spell," but it is not clear whether there is actually something supernatural at play. What accounts for the popularity of this idea among people in Lyra's world, and in particular, why does Lyra herself seem to take it at least semi-seriously?

Note also it's mentioned that one of the books is about a boy without a demon who kills god, but weirdly no mention that's literally what Will did.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
